# Is as.vector() for POSIXct objects buggy?

Tags: r, posixct

**The funny part**

Let's start with the set-up (R console):

```
> z <- Sys.time()
> z
[1] "2022-03-15 00:21:42 CET"
> class(z)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Now, the plot (as in joke, not graphics):

```
> as.numeric(z)
[1] 1647300102
> as.character(z)
[1] "2022-03-15 00:21:42"
```

Now, the punch line (also as in joke, not graphics):

```
> as.vector(z, "numeric")
[1] 1647300102
> as.vector(z, "character")
[1] "1647300102.23863"
```

Intuitively, `as.vector(z, "character")` should return *the same* as `as.character(z)`, but it doesn't. Funny, isn't it?

**The serious part**

I think I understand why `as.vector()` with `mode="character"` gives the number-of-seconds-since-epoch instead of the human-readable date-time returned by `as.character()`: the `POSIXct` class has an implementation for the `as.character()` generic, but the guys in charge didn't bother to provide a custom `as.vector()` implementation for this class; hence, `as.vector()` defaults to the base class of `POSIXct` (which is `numeric`) to print the date-time as a `character` vector.

*The question is: should be this reported as a bug?*

I apologize for asking this question here before going head-on to the R core development team; here's why:

**The question part**

Should this be a bug? I would rather ask the community at large first, before asking the R core guys, because `POSIXct` is -- indeed -- one of the `base` R types, but I don't know if this bothers any actual R users (excepting me). My problem with the behaviour is very specific (i.e. using a generic `as.vector(x, mode)` for conversion instead of specific `as.character(x)`, `as.numeric(x)`, `as.MaryPoppins(x)` etc.)

**The reason-for-question part**

The reasons for my asking the question are here:

- The CRAN [Bug reporting in R](https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html) essentially says "if it seems unexpected to you, probably is in your head, unless something crashes". That is not my idea of "bug". But maybe I misunderstood.
- I wonder if other R users would find the behaviour described above surprising. If yes, then maybe this can be reported as an "enhancement" instead as a bug, but with similar outcome (i.e. fixing the behaviour of `as.vector` to be... sane? about the `POSIXct`).
- I wonder also how much legacy code relies on the existing behaviour of `as.vector()` when the main argument is of class `POSIXct`. If there are a lot of users counting on the current behaviour, then maybe I should write my own `as.vector.POSIXct()` methods.

I appreciate all the comments, including the disparaging ones.

**Update: The meta-question**

Just in case you've thought of a workaround using conversion to/from `character` via `format()`... is not exactly the point. The point is: should we expect a consistent interface from the classes in the `base` namespace or not? Ok, now I sound like a revolutionary confined in a Pokemon ball...

Comment: I am a little surprised, but not very--I know dates and datetimes are more complicated than they seem. I'm not sure it qualifies as an API bug, some people may even want this behavior, and my assumption is that R Core will prefer to not make a code change for this. I do think it should be documented. The *Details* section at `?as.vector` calls out `factors` and explains the behavior; suggesting a similar addendum for dates and datetimes would probably be welcomed (and be a friendly way to start the discussion).

Comment: Interesting question. I don't know that I've ever use `as.vector`, so this is new to me. Frankly, it seems odd but nothing I'm going to rant about. Why is this important to you? Is there a use-case where you *must* use `as.vector` in lieu of `as.numeric` or `as.character`?

Comment: If most of what you're looking for is a method to convert an input to another class specified as a string, rolling your own might be best. `as_ = function(x, class) {switch(class, integer = as.integer(x), numeric = as.numeric(x), character = as.character(x), ...)}`

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for the comment. I thought there is a simple solution to my programming problem, i.e. setting a parameter in a convertor, instead of dispatching convertors based on input and output type.

The problem I raised seemed like an inconsistency in the interface of the the POSIXct/POSIXlt classes (BTW, as.vector() with POSIXlt is even crazier). I just wonder if solving this inconsistency "for me" would actually eliminate a world of confusion among all the R programmers.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the input. I thought that `as.vector()` correctly implemented by the classes in `base` namespace would save me from rolling my own convertors. But... hey, at least is possible to roll my own! :-) The drawback is: the implementation of the base classes will change in the future, or someone else will roll the same functions in a different imported namespace, with a different implementation and then... the real fun begins! That's why I wonder if is not better for things to be fixed in the base.

Comment: Good points. I don't know that I can offer much here, good luck!

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question for the `R-devel` [mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-devel). (The question being: Should `base` export a method `as.vector.POSIXt`?)

Comment: *"The drawback is: the implementation of the base classes will change in the future"*, that shouldn't be a concern here. R Core's extreme reluctance to make potentially breaking changes is exactly why I don't think they'll change this behavior, but it also means you don't have to worry about that. And besides, you're just doing your own dispatch, not your own coercion. If the `as.character()` method changes or needs updating for some particular class, you calling `as.character()` will still work fine.

Comment: @GregorThomas Yeah! Remembering how many versions it took to change de default `stringsAsFactors` from `TRUE` to `default.stringsAsFactors()` in the `data.frame` construtor is definitely an argument for optimism. :-)